# how to create a defaultHandler java spring 6.0.11

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference ch 17.4 mentions that RequestMappingHandlerMapping is configured by default and that you can set the defaultHandler attribute to a handler for anything that the handlers you specify cannot map. However, I have read the entire MVC doc, and even looked at past docs where handler mappings were not so automatically configured and I cannot figure out how to make a handler to put as a default. Apart from actually knowing how to do this, can anyone tell me how I was supposed to do this using the official spring docs? Is something this fundamental just learned through experience and word of mouth?

This is my config class for my one servlet, at the very bottom I create a RequestMappingHandlerMapping but I do not know what to use at the argument for setDefaultHandler() or how I would go about finding out how to create a class for this.

```
package com.sp.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import com.sp.controllers.MainController;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.sp"})
public class ServicePlatformConfig {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
        
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUsername("");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/service_platform?useSSL=false");
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Autowired
    public MainController mainController;


    
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
        
        handlerMapping.setDefaultHandler(mainController);
        return handlerMapping;
        
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter handlerMappingAdapter() {
        RequestMappingHandlerAdapter handlerMappingAdapter = new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
        MainController mc = new MainController();
        List al = new ArrayList();
        al.add(mc);
        handlerMappingAdapter.setReturnValueHandlers(al);
        return handlerMappingAdapter;
        
    }
}
```

main controller

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
    
    @Autowired
    private TicketDAO TicketDAO;

    
    @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showHomepage(Model model) {
        List<Ticket> ticketList = TicketDAO.loadTickets();
        model.addAttribute("tickets", ticketList);
        for(Ticket ticket : ticketList) {
            System.out.println(":0 keep going");
            System.out.println(ticket);
        }
        
        return "ticket-list";
    }
    
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping
    public String error() {
        
        System.out.println("test test test");
        return "test test test";
    }
}
```

error when going to a link that doesnt map:

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/service-platform] threw exception [No adapter for handler [com.sp.controllers.MainController@72473f59]: The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler] with root cause
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler [com.sp.controllers.MainController@72473f59]: The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandlerAdapter(DispatcherServlet.java:1316)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1064)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:676)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)

Comment: What isn't clear about setting the default handler? You already have it in place but commented it. It can be anything from a `Controller` (the interface) to a class annotated with `@Controller` and properly annotated methods or even a `HttpRequestHandler`. Any type that is understood by the MVC material. Also are you really on Spring 3.2 or are you confusing Spring Boot 3.2 and Spring here? If you are you should really really upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for having me clarify, I am using Spring 6.0.11. Documentation for that actually does not mention setting a default controller on RequestMappingHandlerMapping, but its a non deprecated field in the class in the latest version. I edited the post to show my set up, and the error message I get when navigating to a non mapped page. Please let me know if I should change my approach to this completely.

Comment: So.. I tried to configure a handler adapter using the API, still get the same error, changes reflected in the post.

Comment: You are just constructing an instance, hence Spring doesn't know about the controller. Just inject the `MainController` into the `handlerMapping` method **or** use `mainController` as a `String`. Spring will then do a lookup for the controller with that name.

Comment: I tried both methods you mentioned, injection shown above, still get thrown the same type of error.

Comment: Why do you have a `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` in there? That is already provided by the defaults from `@EnableWebMvc`.

Comment: because of the exception:  " [No adapter for handler [com.sp.controllers.MainController@72473f59]: The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler]"  thrown every time I try to navigate to a page that doesn't map to a specific handler/controller. I was trying to configure a HandlerAdapter for MainController, but in fact commenting it out doesn't change the exception. I guess the good thing is that a default handler has now been mapped because I mapped MainController as the default and it goes to it, but somehow its not set up to handle.